# FastAPI Custom Websocket Object

Tags: fastapi

I want to be able to create a custom WebSocket object rather than using Starlette's so that I can add some more things in the constructor and add some more methods. In FastAPI, you're able to subclass the APIRoute and pass in your own Request object. How would I do the same for the WebSocket router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to set the websocket route class (short of a lot of subclassing and rewriting). I think the simplest way to do this would be to define your own wrapper class around the websocket, taking whatever extra data you want, and then define the methods you need. Then you can inject that as a dependency, either with a separate function, or use the [class itself as a dependency, see the documentation for details](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/?h=classes#classes-as-dependencies_1), which is what I'm doing below.

I've put together a minimal example, where the URL parameter `name` is passed to the wrapper class:

```py
# main.py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, WebSocket

app = FastAPI()


class WsWrapper:
    def __init__(self, websocket: WebSocket, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.websocket = websocket

    # You can define all your custom logic here, I'm just adding a print
    async def receive_json(self, mode: str = "text"):
        print(f"Hello from {self.name}", flush=True)
        return await self.websocket.receive_json(mode)


@app.websocket("/{name}")
async def websocket(ws: WsWrapper = Depends()):
    await ws.websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await ws.receive_json()
        print(data, flush=True)
```

You can test it by running `uvicorn main:app` and connecting to `ws://localhost:8000/test`, and it should print "Hello from test" when receiving JSON.

Comment: future readers: please track https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/4968

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just monkeypatching the modules. Track this PR for when monkeypatching isn't necessary: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/4968

```py
from typing import Callable

from fastapi import routing as fastapi_routing
from starlette._utils import is_async_callable
from starlette.concurrency import run_in_threadpool
from starlette.requests import Request as StarletteRequest
from starlette.websockets import WebSocket as StarletteWebSocket
from starlette.types import ASGIApp, Receive, Scope, Send

class Request(StarletteRequest):
    pass

class WebSocket(StarletteWebSocket):
    pass

def request_response(func: Callable) -> ASGIApp:
    """
    Takes a function or coroutine `func(request) -> response`,
    and returns an ASGI application.
    """
    is_coroutine = is_async_callable(func)

    async def app(scope: Scope, receive: Receive, send: Send) -> None:
        request = Request(scope, receive=receive, send=send)
        # Force all views to be a coroutine
        response = await func(request)
        if is_coroutine:
            response = await func(request)
        else:
            response = await run_in_threadpool(func, request)
        await response(scope, receive, send)

    return app


fastapi_routing.request_response = request_response

def websocket_session(func: Callable) -> ASGIApp:
    """
    Takes a coroutine `func(session)`, and returns an ASGI application.
    """
    # assert asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func), "WebSocket endpoints must be async"

    async def app(scope: Scope, receive: Receive, send: Send) -> None:
        session = WebSocket(scope, receive=receive, send=send)
        await func(session)

    return app


fastapi_routing.websocket_session = websocket_session
```